# Refer to Column by Content of Another Column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a Dataframe of the following pattern

```
+---+---+---+---+
|ref|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  2|  3|  4|
|  C|  9|  8|  7|
|  B|  5|  6|  7|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to have a new column that contains the value of the column referenced in `ref`, so

```
+---+
|new|
+---+
|  2|
|  7|
|  6|
+---+
```

An explicit solution would be `df.withColumn("new", F.when(df.ref == "A", df.A).when(...))`, but since I don't know in advance what values `ref` can contain, I would need a way to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You already have PySpark tagged so lets stick to PySpark and the functionality it can offer:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ref': ['A', 'C', 'B'],
    'A': [2, 9, 5],
    'B': [3, 8, 6],
    'C': [4, 7, 7],
})

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

to get a column like you want, it would seem like a simple expression like this could get the job done:

`` CASE WHEN ref = 'A' THEN `A` WHEN ref = 'B' THEN `B` WHEN ref = 'C' THEN `C` END ``

Instead of programmatically generating the column, you could programmatically generate the expression like this:

```py
expression = "CASE "
for column in df.columns:
    if column != "ref":
        expression += f"WHEN ref = '{column}' THEN `{column}` "
expression += "END"
```

which should solve the issue you're having.

---

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
df_with_new = df.withColumn("new", expr(expression))
df_with_new.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
|ref|  A|  B|  C|new|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  2|  3|  4|  2|
|  C|  9|  8|  7|  7|
|  B|  5|  6|  7|  6|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping to dynamically substitute the values

```
from itertools import chain

mapping = F.create_map(*chain(*[(F.lit(c), F.col(c)) for c in df.columns]))
df = df.withColumn('new', mapping[F.col('ref')])
```

---

```
# +---+---+---+---+---+
# |ref|  A|  B|  C|new|
# +---+---+---+---+---+
# |  A|  2|  3|  4|  2|
# |  C|  9|  8|  7|  7|
# |  B|  5|  6|  7|  6|
# +---+---+---+---+---+
```